# Drawing on BufferedImage in thread

Tags: java, multithreading, canvas, bufferedimage

I'm trying to draw on a BufferedImage from a thread, then displaying said image on a canvas.
Everything works fine when I alter the BufferedImage from within the paintComponent-method of the Canvas, but as soon as I try to alter it from a running thread - nothing happens.

In other words; If I copy the Graphics2D-code from the thread to the paintComponent-method, everything works fine.

A snippet of my code (some of the variables/values are temporary):

```
class DrawThread implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Graphics2D g2d = canvas.getImage().createGraphics(); 

            g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);

            Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(10, 0, 20, 20);

            g2d.draw(rect2);
            g2d.dispose();

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class RectangleCanvas extends Canvas 
{
    public BufferedImage image;

    public RectangleCanvas() 
    {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280, 280));
        image = new BufferedImage(50, 50, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    }

    public synchronized BufferedImage getImage()
    {
        return this.image;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(getImage(), 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1- Give `RectangleCanvas` a copy of the updated `BufferedImage`, NOT the same instance, but another copy. This will allow the canvas to continue painting that copy as needed, but prevent it from painting one that is been changed. 2- Call `repaint` on `RectangleCanvas` when you want it updated...

Comment: You might like to have a look at [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html) and [`BufferStrategy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html)

Comment: It seems that simply calling 'repaint' made it work! But I will certainly look into the other things as well. Thank you so much!